# Parsing for RGB regions over thousands of high resolution image files

Tags: scala, parsing, dictionary, png

I have lots of high resolution image files that have regions of colors, basically blobs with different rgb values. I need to go through the images and for every image make a text file that contains the coordinates to one pixel in every blob. Because I have so many files the script needs to be fast. I already wrote some scala code to do the task except it only saves locations for one blob per specific RGB value, meaning if I have two blobs of the same color that are not connected it will only save one the location for the first one found. The solution to this is for each images copy the location and colors to a map and when I find a blob flood delete (flood fill except delete instead of fill) and then keep parsing on the new map. However, I think this will make run time horribly slow because I will have to go through the entire image to add it to a map before even starting the parse. Thoughts? Am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "map" here? A Scala Map?  That seems a very odd choice for this image processing application (and, unless this is an assignment, rolling your own here seems wrong, you should look for an image-processing package/library).

Comment: It's not an assignment and yes I mean Scala's Map. Java has Image processing libraries that I've used but there's no way that I know of to delete previously checked pixels.

Comment: That's not how you do it. One way - make an array of the same size as your image  to hold "blob ids"  and assign a unique id to every blob of the same colour. You do this using something like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling.

Comment: It also parallelizes like heck, so it's a pity it looks like scaleCL isn't active (https://github.com/nativelibs4java/ScalaCL). Or take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV